# Get a value just edited from controller to Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, controller-extension, extension

I'm building a Visualforce page that let's the user upload some images, they can add as many images as they want, when they click on the "add new" button, a new record is inserted and one of the record fields is the path where it'll be uploaded to.

Here's the button and the action related:

```
<apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!createFile}" name="createRecord" reRender="none"/> 
</apex:form>

<input class="btn" type="button" id="add-btn" value="{!$Label.Add_New}" onclick="createRecord()" />
```

and the createRecord method:

```
public String fileName {get;set;}

public void createFile(){
    String folder = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('orgId');
    try {
        Custom_Object__c file = new Custom_Object__c();
    //Some fields get assigned
        insert file;

        Transient Custom_Object__c tmpFile = [SELECT Path__c FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE Id = :file.Id limit 1];
        fileName = folder + tmpFile.Path__c + ‘.jpg’;
        System.debug(fileName);
    } catch (DMLException e){
        System.debug('DML EXCEPTION: ' + e);
    } catch (QueryException e) {
        System.debug('Query EXCEPTION: ' + e);
    }  
}
```

Then I'm getting the `fileName`value in order to upload the file.

```
<form
    action="https://someurl.com/"
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="key"  value="{!fileName}" /> 

    <input type="file" size="255" name="file" />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="{!$Label.Upload}"/>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I called the `createRecord`function with the `reRender="none"` to prevent it from refresh the entire page, the `{!fileName}` call doesn't get the just updated value. When I remove the `reRender="none"` it gets the new value just fine, I need it to get the new value without refreshing the entire page, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about what rerender does.  It let's you specify what you want to rerender.

Give your form an Id and then do your rerender="formId".  This will rerender that section of the page and so update the value.

```
<form action="https://someurl.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formId">
```

and

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!createFile}" name="createRecord" reRender="formId" />
```

Comment: Just tried it and didn't work.

Comment: your answer didn't work, but gave me an idea, I placed the `<form>` tag inside an `<apex:outputPanel>`and called it in the `<apex:actionFunction action="{!createFile}" name="createRecord" reRender="upload-panel" />` and it worked perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad i could help!